# How to group a bunch of objects into one gameobject on a button press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i challenged myself to make a little game where you build a rocket and then you press the button it launches

i want to it to group up all of the objects and adds a placement script to the parent object all within a script i do not know if this is even possible in unity but if there are other methods or others that are better

using tags did not work i want to let them group up and launch!

Comment: How have you selected which objects to group? Or is it “all” objects of a certain type that are in the scene? Does ordering matter? Ie a nose cone should be highest in the list of grouped objects? Is ordering already taken care of in the position of the object?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you instantiate a piece, cache a reference to it. When it's time to launch, use the first cached reference as the parent and then, for each other piece, set its parent to be the first piece. It'd look something like

```
for(int i=1; i<parts.Count; i++)
{
    parts[i].transform.parent = parts[0].transform;
}
```